# How to update the Frame's schema after Map.apply operation?

Tags: aws-glue

I'm seeing some very strange behavior out of the AWS Glue Map operator. First, it looks like you have to return a DynamicRecord and there doesn't seem to be a way to create a new DyanmicRecord. The example that is in the AWS Glue Map documentation edits the DynamicRecord passed in. However, when I edit the DynamicRecord passed in the schema becomes just `root` and the resulting dataset when outputted via Spigot is the original dataset passed into Map.

Has anyone gotten the Map operator to work? If so can you provide a snippet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try converting the `DynamicDataframe` to spark dataframe by `.toDF()`

Comment: I was actually throwing an exception in the map function. Which it looks like glue fails silently and returns the original frames unless you implement error handling in your map function.
However, even after fixing that the schema after map was incorrect. I was able to use a ResolveChoice with choice type set to `MATCH_CATALOG`.

Comment: A solution for anyone facing this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51451205/2028733

Answer (score 3):

Are you returning updated record?

```
def MergeAddress(rec):
  rec["Address"] = {}
  rec["Address"]["Street"] = rec["Provider Street Address"]
  rec["Address"]["City"] = rec["Provider City"]
  rec["Address"]["State"] = rec["Provider State"]
  rec["Address"]["Zip.Code"] = rec["Provider Zip Code"]
  rec["Address"]["Array"] = [rec["Provider Street Address"], rec["Provider City"], rec["Provider State"], rec["Provider Zip Code"]]
  del rec["Provider Street Address"]
  del rec["Provider City"]
  del rec["Provider State"]
  del rec["Provider Zip Code"]
  return rec

mapped_dyF =  Map.apply(frame = dyF, f = MergeAddress)
mapped_dyF.printSchema()
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-transforms-map.html

Comment: yes, see the comment on the accepted answer. I added a try-except clause and logged the map errors. Looks like Glue's map function fails silently and returns the original frames if you throw in the map function.

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to log from inside a mapping functions, e.g. here from `MergeAddress`. I can see my logs that I print outside mapping function, but the ones from inside are nowhere to be seen.